# Libgdx draw textures on Fixtures

Tags: libgdx

What is a common way to draw textures on fixtures of bodies? The texture I want to use ist just a 1x1pixel texture with a color. I have bodies made of a lot of rectangle shaped polygons (rotated in different directions).
Do I have to iterate over all fixtures and calculate their angle etc. and then draw my 1x1 texture?
Or is there a more efficient way of doint that?